# Formula to obtain amount to add to Starting Value so the added amount will = 5% of New Total

Tags: t-sql, formula

Is there a formula that will work in T-SQL that can obtain the following?

Solve for x where adding x to starting value, will equal 105% of starting value.

**Example**
Starting value of 380.
Add x to 380 so that x is 5% of total (380 + x)
In this case, x is an even 20.

*This is not 5% of the Starting value, which, would be simple. I'm looking for x to equal 5% of the new value after it's been added to the starting value.*

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm looking for x to equal 5% of the new value after it's been added to the starting value.

Let's do some 9th grade algebra :) I'll even show my work.

If `S` is the starting value, we have this equation:

```
x = 0.05 * (S + x)
```

Now solve for `x`:

```cs
x = 0.05S + 0.05x      // distribute the constant

0.95x = 0.05S          // subtract the smaller x term from both sides

x = (0.05 / 0.95) * S  // divide the 0.95 from both sides

x = S / 19             // multiply the right side by 1 (20/20) to simplify
```

So we see you can divide the starting value by 19 to get the desired x value.

---

And an alternative way to solve the equation, because I think this kind of thing is fun:

```cs
x = (1/20) * (S + x)   // convert the decimal to a fraction 

x = (S + x) / 20       // reduce/simplify the fraction multiplication

20x = S + x            // multiply both sides by 20, to remove division

19x = S                // subtract the smaller x term from both sides
                       //   (hey, we solved for S along the way)

x = S / 19             // Divide both sides by 19
```

It's always nice when two approaches give the same solution :). This was more steps, but the steps were simpler.